# how to get the class name of a span using xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler

I was trying to get the `class` name of the first `span` of `header` class.
In this case, I would like to print out "all-star 40 main-title-rating".

I successfully printed out the user name, in this case, "lemon".
But I didn't know how to access the class name and get the rating.

Thank you!

```
<header class="main-hd">
    <a href="https://www.douban.com/people/lime/" class="avator">
        <img width="24" height="24" src="https://img3.doubanio.com/icon/u1023412-1.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.douban.com/people/lime/" class="name">lemon</a>
        <span class="allstar40 main-title-rating" title="推荐"></span>
    <span content="2005-09-26" class="main-meta">2005-09-26 17:20:32</span>
</header>

headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/534.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.50"}
url="https://movie.douban.com/subject/1291561/?from=showing"
data=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
from lxml import etree
selector=etree.HTML(data.text)
comments = selector.xpath('//div[@class="main review-item"]')
for comment in comments{
    user = comment.xpath('.//header/a/text()')
    print(user)
    rate = comment.xpath('.//header/span[1]/element')
    print(rate)
}
```

There is no error, but nothing was printed for the rating.

Thanks ~

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `@class` to the xpath:

```
rate = comment.xpath('//header/span[1]/@class')
print(rate)
```

See [this example](http://xpather.com/Q23L8Zdd).

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer css selectors and use the just extract the class

```
ratings = [(item.select_one('.name').text, ' '.join(item.select_one('.main-title-rating')['class'])) for item in soup.select('.review-item')]
```

You could use split or re to extract the actual number of stars:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://movie.douban.com/subject/1291561/?from=showing')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
ratings = [(item.select_one('.name').text, re.search(r'(\d)',item.select_one('.main-title-rating')['class'][0]).groups(0)[0] ) for item in soup.select('.review-item')]
print(ratings)
```